# Why am I not able to pass to a perl script a variable string for sprintf?

Tags: perl, printf

I come with the following perl problem. Take this piece of code and put it into test.pl

```
my $str=shift;

printf "$str", @ARGV;
```

Then run it like this:

```
perl test.pl "x\tx%s\n%s" one two three
```

The expected output for me should be:

```
x    xone
two
```

Instead I got

```
x\sxone\ntwo
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perl converts escape sequences within strings at compile time, so once your program is running you are too late to have `"\t"` and `"\n"` converted to tab and newline.

Using `eval` would fix this, but it's very insecure. I recommend you use the [`String::Interpolate`](https://metacpan.org/module/String%3a%3aInterpolate) module to process strings after compilation. It uses Perl's native interpolation engine so has the exact same effect as if you had coded the string into your program.

Your `test.pl` becomes

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use String::Interpolate qw/ interpolate /;

my $str = shift;

printf interpolate($str), @ARGV;
```

**output**

```
E:\Perl\source>perl test.pl "x\tx%s\n%s" one two three
x       xone
two
E:\Perl\source>
```

---

**Update**

If you just want to allow for a small subset of the possibilities that `String::Interpolate` supports then you could write something explicit like, say

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = shift;

$str =~ s/\\t/\t/g;
$str =~ s/\\n/\n/g;

printf $str, @ARGV;
```

but a module or `eval` are the only real ways to support a general Perl string on the command line.

Comment: So the only way of doing this using standard perl modules is `eval`, right?

Comment: @thebrxinthewalls: Yes, although you could code a few special cases. See my update. What is the problem with using a non-core module? Installing modules is really very easy.